# Google endpoint: Access auth api from native client

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I try to access a google endpoint service from a native application with OAuth 2.0. I managed to authenticate with GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow and the JavaFX webview (as browser). 
After a successfull authentication I try to access the api method but the User object is always null and the question is why?

Code for api method call:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = getGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow();
Credential credential = flow.loadCredential(USER_ID);
Helloworld.Builder builder = new Helloworld.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), 
                                               new JacksonFactory(), credential);
Helloworld service = builder.build();
Helloworld.Greetings.Authed protectedApiMethod = service.
                                             greetings().authed();
HelloGreeting execute = protectedApiMethod.execute();
System.out.println("Response " + execute.getMessage());
```

Code for creating the flow object:

```
private static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow getGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow() {
    return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new NetHttpTransport(), 
       new JacksonFactory(), INSTALLED_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(SCOPE_EMAIL));
}
```

Code where I try to authenticate:

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = getGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow();
GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest tokenRequest = flow.newTokenRequest(code);
tokenRequest.setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URL);
    try {
        GoogleTokenResponse execute = tokenRequest.execute();
        flow.createAndStoreCredential(execute, USER_ID);
        Platform.exit();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Declaration of the Api method:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "greetings.authed",
           path = "greeting/authed",
          clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.INSTALLED_ID,     
              Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID})
public HelloGreeting authedGreeting(User user) {
    if (user != null) {
        HelloGreeting response = new HelloGreeting("hello " + user.getEmail());
        return response;
    } else {
        HelloGreeting response = new HelloGreeting("no user object was specified");
        return response;
    }
}
```

The only response I get is "no user object was specified". Since I can call the method without any error I guess I'm authenticated correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/getstarted/backend/auth

> If the request coming in from the client has a valid auth token or is
>   in the list of authorized clientIDs, the backend framework supplies a
>   valid User to the parameter. If the incoming request does not have a
>   valid auth token or if the client is not on the clientIDs whitelist,
>   the framework sets User to null

So, you have to manully catch the case, where a null user is supplied by the infrastructure. So to answer the above question: The request is invalid. And the mistake in the code is, that the CodeFlow object is recreated for the actual request but since no CredentialStore is set, the token is lost and cannot be resend.